# Declarative routing in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

We are converting an existing Webforms site to MVC. The current URL structure is like http://site/City-Category-State, where spaces in city and category are also hyphens, so the URL would be /New-York-Small-Business-NY. A company URL structure is http://site/Company-City-Category-State so that would be /Company-ABC-New-York-Small-Business-NY. As you can see there is really no way to map it back to Category or Company Controllers directly. This is why we are thinking of using a declarative routing where an XML document will map URLs to controllers. Where can I put the code to read XML and assign controller/actions to the route?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a siteController with an index method and route everything to that, then you can have your index method take the whole "City-Category-State" as a parameter and parse it, then redirect to the appropriate controller with the right values, or just return the view right there.

Comment: To expound on this, you need to use a "slug" variable, which looks like this, and must be the last bit of the url template:  `{*yourvariablename}`

Comment: But that's like creating a fake controller that catches everything and then just sends it to another controller right? I was hoping to do it via routing so the request is directly routed to the correct controller.

Comment: What kind of controller structure were envisioning?  Are you going to explicitly create controller methods for each city?